# Unable to connect to Websocket over WSS on HTTPS page

Tags: websocket, https, wss

i'm stuck really stuck, i'm on apache 2.4 on a godaddy VPS server running almaliux8 and i'm trying to build a customer loyalty app for my company using Websockets to communicate between the cashier and the customer. Without even trying to build the app, i'm testing the infrastructure of building a WSS websocket for my HTTPS website. I've followed all the tutorials and forums as best as i can but i'm still relatively cluless. Please see the php and configs below. I'm able to connect to the websocket on ws://site.com:8091 wihtout any issues, but switching to wss://site.com/ gives me a 404 error. i've tried everything from the /wss2/ to checking firewall settings and even chatgpt but have not been able to get any progress. Appreciate some comments.

I've added the following in one of the included files for my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:8091/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:8091/$1 [P,L]
    ServerName www.lamskitchen.co

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / ws://localhost:8091/
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://localhost:8091/

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/website.co.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/website.co.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/website.co.bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The following is the Chat.php class file config

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;
    protected $clientCount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->clientCount = 0;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        $this->clientCount++;

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        echo "Received message from {$from->resourceId}: {$msg}\n";

        // Pass the received message to all other clients
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        $this->clientCount--;

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred for connection {$conn->resourceId}: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

And finally the socket.php file

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$sslContext = [
    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => '/etc/ssl/certs/lamskitchen.co.crt',
        'local_pk' => '/etc/ssl/private/lamskitchen.co.key',
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
];

$chat = new Chat(); // Replace with your Chat application class

$wsServer = new WsServer($chat);

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer($wsServer),
    8091,
    '0.0.0.0',
    $sslContext
);

$wsServer->enableKeepAlive($server->loop, 10);

$server->run();
```